# Passing environment varibale from one go stage to another

Tags: go-cd

We have a pipeline job with 2 stages and we have declared an environment variable.
We are changing value of environment variable in stage 1 and now I want to used changed value of environment variable in stage 2.
But it is not using a changed value in stage 2.
We  have tried using environment variable on Pipeline level, job level and stage level.
Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to pass an environment variable from stage 1 to stage 2. The only way that I have been dealing with this situation is to echo the environment variable to a text file and pas the text file along as an artifact between the two stages.

Comment: Shame that downstream pipelines cannot access the env vars of parents.